# How to burn torrent movies to a dvd-rw that work!

Tags: dvd, burning

I just downloaded ubuntu to my Dell laptop and I'm about 6 hrs new to this system. On my girlfriends windows 7 laptop I burnt the movie frozen to a dvd-rw and put it in the xbox, ps4, and a portable dvd player but none of them worked.

Since I am new to this ubuntu I am wondering what type of programs will I need and how can burn working movies to a dvd-rw that works in most movie players like xbox, ps4, or most dvd players.

Comment: You should use Brasero, a Nero Burning ROM analog for Linux. It can write DVD or Video CD.

Comment: For best compatibility you should convert the movies to [DVD-Video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvd_video) format. This process is called **authoring** and DeVeDe does a good and straightforward job at that. So it's not about burning, but about what data you burn onto the media, given that the target drive can read DVD-RW media.

Answer (score 2):

From https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Brasero:

> ### What is Brasero?
>
> Brasero is an application to burn CD/DVD for the Gnome Desktop. It is
> designed to be as simple as possible and has some unique features to
> enable users to create their discs easily and quickly.
>
> ### Features
>
> - Supports multiple backends: cdrtools, growisofs and libburn(optional).
>
> Note: compiling against libburn is ***not*** enough. You need to activate
> the backend through GSettings
>
> ### Data CD/DVD
>
> - supports edition of discs contents (remove/move/rename files inside directories)
> - can burn data CD/DVD on the fly
> - automatic filtering for unwanted files (hidden files, broken/recursive symlinks, files not conforming to joliet standard,
>   ...)
> - supports multisession
> - supports joliet extension
> - can write the image to the hard drive
> - can check disc file integrity
>
> ### Audio CD
>
> - write CD-TEXT information (automatically found thanks to gstreamer)
> - supports the edition of CD-TEXT information
> - can burn audio CD on the fly
> - can use all audio files handled by Gstreamer local installation (ogg, flac, mp3, ...)
> - can search for audio files inside dropped folders
> - full edition of silences between tracks
>
> ### CD/DVD copy
>
> - can copy a CD/DVD to the hard drive
> - can copy CD and DVD on the fly
> - supports single-session data DVD
> - supports any kind of CD
>
> ### Others
>
> - erase CD/DVD
> - can save/load projects
> - can burn CD/DVD images and cue files
> - song, image and video previewer
> - device detection thanks to HAL
> - file change notification (requires kernel > 2.6.13)
> - a customisable GUI (when used with GDL)
> - supports Drag and Drop / Cut'n'Paste from nautilus (and others apps)
> - can use files on a network as long as the protocol is handled by gnome-vfs
> - can search for files thanks to beagle (search is based on keywords or on file type)
> - can display a playlist and its contents (note that playlists are automatically searched through beagle)
> - all disc IO is done asynchronously to prevent the application from blocking

Comment: Now, how does one author a DVD in DVD-Video format with Brasero? You're **not answering** the question. Besides Ubuntu comes with [cdrkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cdrkit) instead of cdrtools, because someone from the Debian community felt the strong need to create a broken competitor.